# Can't figure out how to format a for loop with if statements

Tags: r

I am in an intro to R course and the professor has not been much help. One of the questions on the latest homework has me stumped. The question is below, along with my answers so far.

```
8. [15 points] Given the following code,
#
# x <- rnorm(10)
#
# Do the following.
#
# (1) create a count vector named "count" of four elements and set each to 0 using the rep function.
# (2) using a for loop to process each value in the vector x, count how many times each of the following values occur in the vector x using an if statement.
# a. "value is between -1 and 1 inclusive"
# b. "value is between -2 and 2 inclusive, but not between -1 and 1",
# c. "value is between -3 and 3 inclusive, but not between -2 and -2", or
# d. "value is greater than 3 or less than -3".
# (3) print each of the four counts in the count vector using a while loop.
#
# For example, if the vector x contains the following ten values,
#
# 1.1478911  1.6183994 -2.3790632 -0.2566993  0.8923735
# -0.7523441 -0.7559083  0.9836396  1.0994189  2.5519972
#
# Then, the output should be as below.
#
# count[1] is 5
# count[2] is 3
# count[3] is 2
# count[4] is 0

x <- rnorm(10)
```

My answers:

(1) `count <- c(rep(0,4))`

(2)

```
for (count in x) {
          if (x > -1 & x < 1) {
                 print(count[1])
```

}

I know there is something wrong with my code for part one but we haven't gone over anything like this in class and I have struggled to find a video for something like this. Please point me in the right direction and let me know what mistakes I have made, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You part one is correct. Maybe you can remove the initial `c()` from it.

```
x <- rnorm(10)
#Part 1
count <- rep(0,4)

#Part 2
for(i in x) {
  if(i >= -1 && i <= 1)
    count[1] <- count[1] + 1
  else  if(i >= -2 && i <= 2)
    count[2] <- count[2] + 1
  else if(i >= -3 & i <= 3)
    count[3] <- count[3] + 1
  else count[4] <- count[4] + 1
}

#Part 3
i <- 0
while (i < length(count)) {
  i <- i + 1
  print(sprintf('count[%d] is: %d', i, count[i]))
}
```

Note that there are better/efficient ways to do this but I think for the purpose of this exercise this is what your professor wants.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the 4 slots in `count` is supposed to keep track of whether a value in `x` satisfies one of the 4 conditions listed (`a.` through `d.`).

If we were to speak it out loud, it'd go something like:

- Look at element 1 in `x` (you can do that with `x[1]`).  It's `1.1478911`.  This satisfies condition `b.`, so add a 1 to the "`b.` counter", which is the second slot in `count`, or `count[2]`.
- Now look at element 2 in `x` (that's `x[2]`)...(and so on, up to the last element in `x`).

To solve this task, you could just write out 10 statements, looking at each of the 10 elements in `x` separately, and update `count` on a case-by-case basis, but that is long and is hard to modify.

A `for`-loop is kind of like making a template for the spoken-out-loud part above.  So instead of saying, "Ok, now we're on Element 3, let's see what the deal is", you can instead say, "Ok, now we're on Element `i`...", where `i` is just a temporary variable, a placeholder that only exists for the life of the `for`-loop.  The `i` placeholder automatically takes on the value of the element in the vector we're iterating over.

If it's `for (i in 1:3)` then `i` will be 1, then 2, then 3.
If it's `for (letter in c("a", "b", "c"))`, then `letter` will be "a", then "b", then "c".

So you can see that when you write `for (count in x)`, that doesn't follow the rules of the `for`-loop.  It's true that we'll want to update `count` at some point in the loop, but you've got it in the spot where our temporary placeholder is supposed to go.  You can call that placeholder whatever you want, but `i` is common when looping over numbers, by convention.

Here's an example: the following code will start `i` at 1, and repeat the code inside the loop statement with new integers, until `i` gets to 10:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  print(paste("i is", i, "and the i'th value of x is", x[i]))
}
```

That should be enough to get you over the part you're stuck on.

A couple of additional hints:

1. f you want to know how many things are in a vector, such as `x`, you can use `length(x)` (try it, you will see the output is 10).  So instead of doing: `for(i in 1:10)`, you can swap out 10 for `length(x)`.
2. `count[3] <- count[3] + 1` adds 1 to whatever the current total is in the third element of `count`.

Good luck!  Someone may post the answer to the whole problem, but if you want to work through each piece, I hope this is a good jump start for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I figured I had something wrong in the "count in x" part, and the professor never even mentioned anything about i in a for loop. I will try to work through it myself before I look into the answer another user gave as I'm sure it is something I will need to learn.