# Trying to create a for loop with nested if statements inside

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

Alright so I'm trying to do an assignment and I'm getting errors back but I'm not sure why. Here's the question, I'll break it up as I go.

Given the following code,
x <- rnorm(10)
Do the following.

(1) create a count vector named "count" of four elements and set each to 0 using the rep function.

So for this part I did

```
count <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
rep(count, each=0)
```

I think this is correct? I don't know what it means by setting each to zero but after some looking around through R's help, I think this is how rep is set up. Correct me if I'm wrong.

(2) using a for loop to process each value in the vector x, count how many times each of the following values occur in the vector x using an if statement.
a. "value is between -1 and 1 inclusive"
b. "value is between -2 and 2 inclusive, but not between -1 and 1",
c. "value is between -3 and 3 inclusive, but not between -2 and -2", or
d. "value is greater than 3 or less than -3".

This is where I'm running into errors. Here's what I've got so far, code-wise

```
for (i in x) {
  if (i >= -1 & i <= 1) print("a") else 
    if (-2 =< i < -1 & 1 < i <= 2) print("b") else
      if (-3 =< i < -2 & 2 < i <= 3) print ("c")
```

When I tried this out, it says "error, unexpected '}' in "      }"
Which I have no idea what that means. I was going to keep going with this code and do else if, with the next set of requirements and so on. But obviously something is wrong and I can't figure out what. When I just had the first part (ending after print "a") it worked just fine. What changed?

(3) print each of the four counts in the count vector using a while loop.

I just straight up don't know what this means.

---

Anyway, I'm really new to R and programming in general, and I feel as if my professor has not really gone this in-depth on this sort of problem, so I'm very lost and turning to the internet for help.

Comment: The first part is not correct. See what it prints to the console if you enter your `rep` command. Maybe want to type `?rep` to see what its expected arguments are. The second part is not quite right. You'll need an assignment in there somewhere to actually update. I also do not believe you can use multiple comparisons like `1 < 2 < 3`. You may want to consider the function `abs`.

Comment: Please reference earlier questions that have been posted on the same issue, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038267/cant-figure-out-how-to-format-a-for-loop-with-if-statements/64038473).  It's the same basic problem, so it's important to show why your question in this post is different.

Comment: @andrew_reece sorry! I did look around for answers to similar questions but did not happen to see this one - I'll check it out, thanks and sorry again.